# JavaScript Input Type Number Restricted to Values 1 and 2

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Probably done with JavaScript.

See this [Example from W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_form_number_adv)

```
<input type="number"  size="2" min="1" max="2">
```

Even with the Min and Max values set, you can still type in whatever number you want and it will accept that value. How do I restrict the user in this case so they can only enter 1 or 2, if they enter something different then it sends an alert and clears the field so the user can try again.

Comment: When do increase or decrease value by click on arrow(right side) then the action will perform according to you. If you put the number mannualy(by typing) then it does not work.

Comment: What does your current javascript code look like, and what specific problems do you have with it?

Comment: You'll probably want to add a keypress event to the input and detect the keycode or value - then take action accordingly.

Comment: On each keypress in the input field you can check if you can validate the input text and do necessary

Comment: @user3362232 but you did not say about restriction on cliking right side arrow.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just use radio buttons for this?

Comment: @Mathletics Good question it has to do with two different systems that are being built where I have to match the input types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity's sake, I'm adding an `id` to your input:

```
<input type="number" id="myInput" size="2" min="1" max="2">
```

Then we can simply add an event listener:

```
document.querySelector('#myInput').addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  if (e.target.value !== '1' && e.target.value !== '2') {
    alert('Invalid number!');
    e.target.value = '';
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/9ZKsP/2/)

Keep in mind, it's rather jarring UX to use `alert`, I'm only using it here for an example.  Instead, you may want to add an `error` class to the element or pop up a modal.

Comment: @Teemu Well, I feel like a dope.  Thanks for the catch, it's fixed now.

Comment: Thanks this is the best solution. I had to put this script at the bottom of the page below the HTML since it uses an event listener. Putting the script at the top didn't work because it didn't load the ID.

Comment: @user3362232 That's correct and best practice.  Glad I could help, and thanks for the accept/upvote!

Answer (score 4):

Without using JS, you can set the `pattern` attribute of the `input` field so the user knows at least that what he/she put in is invalid. This will not clear the field however.

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/k_rma/m6wpF/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="number" size="2" min="1" max="2" pattern="[12]">
```

**CSS**

```css
input:invalid { color:red; border:2px solid red; }
```

Comment: True, but you'll have trouble carrying this method forward if you want to include numbers with more than a single digit in your range.

Comment: I like this option as well I'm using it with the alert. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind having a standard error message on invalid input, you can also use:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[1-2]">
```

Edit: If you add a "title" attribute to the input, you can set the error message you want.

Answer (score 1):

The example is using the [HTML 5 input type number](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html), which not all browsers support consistently.

You could limit this range using JavaScript, perhaps using jQuery. This is definitely an improvement over the code above, but in truth in a real-world application you accomplish this by using a framework component like [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/), [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/), or [jQuery Validator](http://jqueryvalidation.org/). Using a framework like this will allow you to manage all of your validation in a central location and implement more complex logic involving multiple properties, such as "Value two must be greater than value one".

Comment: Attribute events makes the markup bigger and less readable. Concerns of content/structure and behavior are not well-separated, making a bug harder to find. Furthermore, usage of event attributes almost always causes scripts to expose global functions on the Window object, polluting the global namespace.

Comment: sorry about that Paul .. as soon as I saw the `onchange` attribute I automatically pasted the comment... if you edit your post I can remove the downvote...

Comment: Killed it least a tl;dr programmer adopt it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery and `checkValidity()` method of the input:

```
$('[name=points]').bind('keyup',function(){
  if (!$(this).get(0).checkValidity()) {
    $(this).val('');
  }
});
```

`checkValidity()` will only work in modern browsers.

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/125666

Answer (score 0):

This is how `<input type=number>` is expected to work: it does not physically prevent the user from entering arbitrary data (well, it might, but it need not), but the control does not satisfy constraints upon form submission, if it does not match the requirements.

If you want to let the user select between two alternatives only, use a checkbox, or two radio buttons, or a `select` element with two options. The details depend on whether this should be an obligatory choice or optional and whether there is a default value.

P.S. W3schools.com is bogus, in this issue, too. The example you link to (which is different from your code) is not strictly incorrect, just illogical and misleading.

Comment: `it does not physically prevent the user from entering arbitrary data` To be fair, that's precisely what `pattern` is for in HTML5.

Comment: @admdrew, the question was not about `pattern`. OTOH, for both `pattern` and `type=number`, the whole Constraint validation API would be pointless if browsers were expected to enforce the constraints at the level of individual constraints.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela `the question was not about pattern` It sure can be! `How do I restrict the user...?`

Comment: Pattern is not the correct solution for restricting the user to a range of numbers.